# How to return an int and a string?

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

I have created a little highscore system that saves to file and then reads/loads on request.

However, I am loading into a vector of strings so have created a string builder to add them and display in order.

However, I've realised this is a bad way of doing it and am unsure how to get the result I want, which would be to have a data structure that could be sorted in order of score(descending) along with the corresponding name.

What I'd like to do in theory is `<vector<int, string> theScore`. If anyone could point me the the right direct I'd really appreciate it.

Here's what I have:

```
vector<string> HighScore::loadScore()
{

ifstream loadFile("scorefile.txt");

string name;
int score;

vector<string> theScore;
string builder;

if (loadFile.is_open())
{
    while (!loadFile.eof())     
    {
        loadFile >> name >> score;

        builder = to_string(score) + "\t";
            builder = builder + name;   

            //Add all entries to vector List
                theScore.push_back(builder);                                
        }   

        //Sort all entries in score to descending order (Reverse)
        std::sort(theScore.rbegin(), theScore.rbegin() +theScore.size());   

    }

    return theScore;
}
```

Comment: Create an class with having a Siring and an int variable and then return the object.

Answer (score 2):

It's not too clear to me what you're trying to do, but I expect
that you want to define a class which contains the necessary
information, and an `operator>>` and `operator<<` for it.  So
you'd end up with something like:

```
std::vector<Entry> data;
Entry entry;
while ( loadFile >> entry ) {
    data.push_back( entry );
}
```

If `Entry` is something like:

```
struct Entry
{
    int score;
    std::string name;
};
```

then your `operator>>` might look like:

```
std::istream&
operator>>( std::istream& source, Entry& dest )
{
    Entry results;
    source >> results.score >> results.name;
    if ( source ) {
        dest = results;
    }
    return source;
}
```

(Or you might want to read a line and parse it, in order to
allow white space in the name.)

To sort, you define simple comparison operators:

```
struct ByScore
{
    bool operator()( Entry const& lhs, Entry const& rhs ) const
    {
        return lhs.score < rhs.score;
    }
};
```

and pass an instance to `std::sort`:

```
std::sort( data.begin(), data.end(), ByScore() );
```

(And I might add: `while ( !loadFile.eof() )` is incorrect, as
is using the results of `>>` without first verifying that they
have succeeded.)

Answer (score 1):

Use a class or a struct. In this case, a struct is probably perfectly fine:

```
struct Score
{
    int score;
    std::string name;
};
```

Comment: remember the semi-colon on your struct!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair):

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>> theScores;
```

Alternatively you could use [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) as well.

Or just, you know, use a structure with the wanted members.

Comment: The only valid answer is to define the class.  You want the members to have meaningful names (_not_ `first` and `second`).  You want to support input and output (operators `>>` and `<<`).  You want to support different comparison criteria (`ByScore` and `ByName`).  All of which calls for a class type (which may have only public members and be introduced by the keyword `struct`, at least in a simple application).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair

You'll need to include the *utility* header file

If your data structure gets more complicated, you would want to do as others have suggested and create your own.

**Example**

```
std::pair<std::string, std::string> foo;

foo = std::make_pair("foo", "bar");

// As a vector incorporating std::pair
std::vector< std::pair<std::string, std::string> > bar;

// Probably a good time to use typedef
typedef std::pair<std::string, std::string> foo_pair;

std::vector<foo_pair> qux;
```

You can simply use the pair as a parameter in your std::vector

As this is an example, you'll have to change the  template parameters to int and string as you require

**Other**

You could use std::tuple but you'll need to make sure your compiler supports C++11

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a [`std::pair<>`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/pair.html).

Your vector would be of type `std::vector< std::pair<int, std::string> >`.

Comment: No.  That's very bad software engineering: his elements should be called `score` and `name`, not `first` and `second`.  (In well written software, there is almost never a use for `std::pair`.)

Comment: STL itself uses `std::pair` extensively (e.g. associative containers), I suppose it is bad software...

Answer (score 0):

I put my 5 cents on `std::vector<std::tuple<int, std::string> >`, you can place additional types into the tuple, if you like. Use `std::make_tuple()` to create tuples.

Comment: See my comments to @nvoigt.  He has a distinct structure, and its elements should have meaningful names.